# Failed building wheel for patchelf Failed to build ninja patchelf ERROR: Could not build wheels for ninja, patchelf

Tags: build

I can't install program because matplotlib and contourpy don't successfully build. Please help here's the error logs. I'm running on an Android 12 termux app not in Linux.

## note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

```
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for patchelf
  Failed to build ninja patchelf
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for ninja, patchelf, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Nothing need new suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

**To install patchelf:**
`pkg install patchelf`

**To install ninja:**
`pkg install ninja`

Comment: For ninja at least, there are some other issues that may also need to be solved; the comments on [this bug](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/8951) give a few suggestions.